# Is it possible to repackage an already installed ubuntu for an OEM install?

Tags: 12.04, iso, oem

I'd like to repackage an install of Ubuntu into an ISO to install it on other systems as OEM with the packages I have installed?

Comment: Hello @swiftimundo. Welcome to AskUbuntu. The solution to your question seems to have been discussed in the past as mentioned in my previous comment. I wonder if you are trying something different than what was asked before and if so, do you mind letting us know in order to provide you with the best support for your sole case? Thank you and Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remastersys is a backup tool that can be used to make an installation iso from an Ubuntu install, including all programs and changes you've made in the generated iso. Remastersys is a dead project, but the precise repository is compatible with Ubuntu 13.04. Remastersys iso files will not boot in UEFI. The GUI is very user friendly and easy to figure out.

**How To Install Remastersys:**<sup>1</sup>

1. Download GPG key: "http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key"
2. In terminal type `sudo software-center` or launch by hand (which is recommended).
3. Open the "Edit" menu. Open the "Authentication" tab. Click "Import Key File".
4. Browse For "remastersys.gpg.key" which you previously downloaded, and click "OK".
5. Open the "Other Software" tab and click "Add". Paste in: `deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main`.
6. In terminal type `sudo apt-get update`
7. In terminal type `sudo apt-get install remastersys`
8. In terminal type `sudo apt-get install remastersys-gui`

**How To Run Remastersys With GUI:** In terminal type `sudo remastersys-gui`

**How To Run Remastersys:** In terminal type `sudo remastersys`

2

<sup>1</sup><sub>Source: http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=827.0</sub>
2

<sub>Source: http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=828.0</sub>